# Can't find DbContext when using Elastic Database Client library, EF and Identity

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

I'm trying to create an MVC WebApp that uses EntityFramework, Identity and Elastic Database Client.

I have gone through the [Microsoft example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-scale-use-entity-framework-applications-visual-studio) and most of it makes sense. However when I create my own MVC project and then add a DAL project including EF, Identity entities and the Elastic Client I cannot run the enable-migrations script.

I've made sure that my Package Manager Console is pointing to the correct DAL project and that my context inherits DbContext. So i'm a bit stumped to see this error message:

```
PM> enable-migrations
No context type was found in the assembly 'LeadEngine.Data'.
PM>
```

Has anybody been able to get these 3 frameworks working together or know why it can't find my context?

P.S. The code for all the sharding is almost a copy from the Microsoft example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After downloaded the sample code, I found that the context type in the sample is generic type. As we know generic type is an open type, we can't create a instance directly from generic type until we append a type parameter to it.

> No context type was found in the assembly 'LeadEngine.Data'.

To use data migrations, you could recreate a new context type which can't be a generic type. Code below is for your reference.

```
public class NewElasticScaleContext : ElasticScaleContext<int>
{
    public NewElasticScaleContext() : base("put connection string here")
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that has resolved it for me. However, it's strange that the example solution cant create it's own Migrations if you run the script. Makes we wonder how that is a valid example and how that really works with Database Pools.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the right project selected when attempting to do a migration.

Check this out: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c9d8b7b9-99c8-47a9-9122-67758ecde9b3/no-context-type-was-found-in-the-assembly?forum=adodotnetentityframework